# Hive IF THEN ELSE for executing different Hive Queries based on conditions

Tags: if-statement, hive, conditional-statements, hiveql

I want to do something like below,

```
IF table1 is not exists THEN

create table1 ();

ELSE 

insert overwrite table1
select ....

END
```

Is this achievable in hive ql ?

This is mainly for incremental load, also merge wont work because the record counts are billions.

Comment: not directly, you can use a workarround. can you do it in 2 step process - 1. use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ` to create the table. 2. then `insert overwrite table1 select ....`. Step1 will create table if it doesnt exist and step2 will load the data

Comment: Wow this is so simple and have solved a huge issue for me. you are a genius, Thanks alot.

Comment: marking it as answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly using single SQL, you can use a workaround. You can use 2 steps.

- use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`  to create the table.
- then run `insert overwrite table1 select .....`

Step1 will create table if it doesnt exist and step2 will load the data